# LUKS terrible write performance on SSD

Tags: partitioning, 18.04, encryption, ssd, luks

Since I encrypted the partitions of `/` and `/home` with LUKS on my notebook, the overall write speed on my ssd is low.

**Hardware & Software**

- Intel i3 4010U 2/4 x 1,70 GHz (with AES-NI)
- Ubuntu 18.04.1
- 2x 2GB DDR3 1600 MHz 2
- 2x Drives
- 1x Crucial CT128M550 SSD an M.2 (Sata 3.0)
- 1x Western Digital HDD an Sata 3.0

**Partitions**

no lvm

```
SSD

Nr Type  Size    FS
1  EFI  256MB   vfat
2  Boot 512MB   ext4
3  /     40GB   ext4 (luks)
4  /home 80GB   btrfs (luks)

HDD

Nr  Type  Size  FS
1   /data 500GB btfs (luks)
```

**Encryption**

I used the same algorithm on all partitions

```
cipher: aes-xts-plain64
keysize: 512 bits
hash:   sha512
```

cryptsetup benchmark

```
aes-xts    512b        684,2 MiB/s     677,9 MiB/s
```

**Benchmark**

I monitored the read and write speed with dd before and after encryption with LUKS

```
# write
dd if=/dev/zero of=tempfile bs=1M count=1024 conv=fdatasync,notrunc 
# drop cache
echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches 
# read
dd if=tempfile of=/dev/null bs=1M count=1024
```

result in MB/s before LUKS

```
SSD
Write  Read
343    561

HDD
Write  Read
106    110
```

result in MB/s after LUKS

```
       FS      Drive   Write-luks   Read-luks
/      ext4    ssd     50           378  
/home  btrfs   ssd     50           543
/data  btrfs   hdd     109          105
```

The read and write speed on the HDD stays the same, but the write speed on the ssd is very low now.

I performed the same benchmark on the "/boot" partition (no luks, ssd) with dd count=256.

```
SSD in MB/s
       FS      Drive   Write        Read
/boot  ext4    ssd     49           527
```

The result shows that the "/boot" partition has the same low write speed than the other encrypted partitions.

I don't understand, why the performance of the hdd stays the same, but the write speed of the ssd is very low, also on not encrypted partitions.

Discard is active on LUKS

```
dmsetup table | grep crypt 
home: 0 [] crypt aes-xts-plain64 [0] 0 8:20 4096 1 allow_discards
root: 0 [] crypt aes-xts-plain64 [0] 0 8:19 4096 1 allow_discards
data: 0 [] crypt aes-xts-plain64 [0] 0 8:1 4096 1 allow_discards
```

I would be thankful for some ideas or help.

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/48304/ssd-luks-performance-comparison